# Meteor : redirect if user didn't create page

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

In Meteor I have a product edit page. I only want the user who created the product to see the page. Otherwise you get redirected.

Is there a way to do this redirect with iron router only?
If not I'll take any solution.

***router.js***

```
var OnBeforeActions;
OnBeforeActions = {
    ownerRequired: function(pause){
      if(!Meteor.userId()){
        Router.go('home');
      }else if(Meteor.userId()._id != ....SOMETHING?....){
        Router.go('home');
      }else{
        this.next();
      }
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(OnBeforeActions.ownerRequired, {
    only: ['editProduct']
});


Router.route('/editProduct/:_id',{
  template: "editProduct",
  name: "editProduct",
  data: function(){
    return Products.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  }
});
```

Comment: for your product, do you currently store the user id of its creator, like a createdBy property?

Comment: yes @williamli i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to know how to solve this ***without iron router***. You could do something like this. (Note I already check with an onBeforeAction if the user is logged in.)

```
Template.editProduct.onCreated(function(){
    if(this.data.user === Meteor.userId()){
    }else{
        Router.go('home');
    }
});
```